# SQL Server - CSV Import Date issue

Tags: sql-server, csv

I'm having issues importing data that looks to me to be relatively simple.  I have the following format in a CSV File:

- "Node1", "Screen.pic", "4/25/2019 9:35:39 AM"
- "Node1", "Screen2.pic", "4/25/2019 9:42:41 AM"
- "Node1", "Screen3.pic", "4/25/2019 9:42:45 AM"

I'm importing it into a datatable that is:

- NodeName - Varchar(50)
- PictureName - Varchar(50)
- dtDateTime - datetime

When I import using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, I get the error "The data conversion for column "csvDateTime" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

The CSV Column configuration I set to Data Type "DT_DBTime", but I have tried about everything.  If I use string, it will just convert it to NULL.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm sure it is simple and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Sounds like the system you're using isn't in American English, and so a date like `4/25/2019` isn't valid (there aren't 25 months in the year). *"If I use string, it will just convert it to NULL."* That doesn't sound right at all, I very much doubt this. Ideally, however, fix your CSV file to use an unambiguous date format.

Comment: The 4 is the month, which is typical in US formatting.  On using string, I did select On Error: Ignore.  which is why when I ran the import it nulled the dtDateTime column.  I can't just fix the CSV file, it is an automatic export from a system.  I'm sure I could insert it by writing a vb.net service - but I don't want to have to go to that effort.

Comment: If you're inserting it into a **`varchar`** column and you're getting errors something is *very* wrong. Choosing to ignore those errors doesn't help you fix that problem.

Comment: I can insert into varchar if I modify the table (dates come in perfectly as strings in that case).  When I change that column to datetime, I cannot.  I want it datetime so that I can run some good date-based queries.

Comment: 4/25/2019 9:42:45 AM will indeed convert to a date provided your date format is MDY.  I suspect some bogus data in the source.   Perhaps you can inspect the source or import as a varchar and then  Select * from YourTable where try_convert(datetime,YourStrCol) is null

Comment: Ah, good point.  I could do a convert, I didn't even think of that. duh. Thank you.

Comment: That's also how I would approach it - import everything into varchar, use `TRY_CAST` / `TRY_CONVERT`  to find the offending data, solve the issue (probably requiring an SSIS derived column) then change back to correct data types.